# Benefits of saving multiple files async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, io, .net-core

I'm writing an action on my controller which saves files to disk. On .Net Core 2.0

I saw some code which saved files like this.

```
foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

This is saving files async but sequentially.  So I decided to write it a bit differently

```
var fileTasks = files.Where(f => f.Length > 0).Select(f => this.SaveFile(f, BASE_PATH));
await Task.WhenAll(fileTasks);

protected async Task SaveFile(IFormFile file, string basePath)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

Assuming I'm saving them all to the same drive, would there be any benefit of doing this?

I'm aware I wouldn't be blocking on any threads, but would would there still be a bottle neck at the Disc?  Or can Modern computers save more than 1 file at once?

Comment: Modern disk drives still only write to one part of the disk at a time.

Comment: @Plutonix does this include SSD's?

Comment: No idea, but it sure would be simple to test and benchmark.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to post this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Its not an answer, just a suggestion to **[race them](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)**

Comment: @Plutonix okay thank you for the help, you saved me some reseach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would would there still be a bottle neck at the Disc? Or can Modern computers save more than 1 file at once?

Yes, and yes. The disk, being orders of magnitude slower than the rest of the computer, will always be a bottle-neck. But, while it is not possible to literally write to more places on a disk at once than there are write heads (rotating media disks almost all have multiple write heads, because there are multiple platters and platter sides on almost all such disks), certainly modern computers (and even not-so-modern computers) can track the I/O for multiple files at once.

The short answer to the broader question: the only way to know for sure, with respect to *any* performance question, is to test it. No one here can predict what the outcome will be. This is true even for relatively simple CPU-bound problems, and it's even more significant when you're dealing with something as complex as writing data to a storage device.

And even if you find you can make the file I/O faster now, that effort may or may not remain relevant in the future. It's even possible you could wind up with your code being *slower* than a simpler implementation.

The longer version…

Issues that affect the actual performance include:

- Type of drive. Conventional hard disks with rotating media are generally much slower than SSD, but each type of drive has its own particular performance characteristics.
- Configuration of drive. Different manufacturers ship drives with different disk RPMs (for rotating drives), different controllers, different cache sizes and types, and varying support for disk protocols. A logical drive might actually be multiple physical drives (e.g. RAID), and even within a drive the storage can be configured differently: rotating media drives can have varying numbers of platters for a given amount of storage, and SSDs can use a variety of storage technologies and arrangements (i.e. single-level vs. multi-level cells, with different block sizes and layouts. **This is far from an exhaustive list of the types of variations one might see in disk drives.**
- File system. Even Windows supports a wide range of file systems, and other OS's have an even broader variety of options. Each file system has specific things it's good at and poor at, and performance will depend on the exact nature of how the files are being accessed.
- Driver software. Drives mostly use standardized APIs and typically a basic driver in the OS is used for all types of drives. But there are exceptions to the rule.
- Operating system version and configuration. Different versions of Windows, or any other OS, have subtly different implementations for dealing with disk I/O. Even within a given version of an OS, a given drive may be configured differently, with options for caching.

Some generalizations can be made, but for every true generalization, there will be an exception. Murphy's Law leads us to conclude that if you ignore real-world testing of your implementation, you'll wind up being the exception.

All that said, it is *possible* that writing to multiple files concurrently can improve throughput, at least for disks with rotating media. Why?

While the comment above from @Plutonix is correct, it does gloss over the fact that the disk controller will optimize as best it can the writes. Having multiple writes queued at once (whether due to multiple files or a single file spread around the disk) allows the disk controller to take advantage of the current position of the disk.

Consider, for example, if you were to write a file one block at a time. You write a block, when you find it's been written, you write another. Well, the disk's moved by the time you get around to writing the next block, so now you get to wait for the proper location to come back around to the write head before the next write can complete.

So, what if you hand over two blocks to the OS at a time? Now, the disk controller can be told about both blocks, and if one block can be written immediately after another, it's there ready to be written. No waiting for another rotation of the disk.

The more blocks you can hand over at once, and the more the disk controller can see to write at once, the better the odds of it being able to write blocks continuously as the platter spins under the write head, without having to pause and wait for the right spot to come back around.

So, why not always write files this way? Well, the biggest reason is that we usually don't need to write data that fast. The user is not inconvenienced by file I/O taking 500 ms instead of 50.

Plus, it significantly increases the complexity of the code.

In addition, the programming frameworks, operating system, file system, and disk controller all have features that provide much or all of the same benefit, without the program itself having to work harder. Buffering at every level of disk I/O means that when your program writes to a file, it thinks the write went really fast, but all that happened was all that data got squirreled away by one or more layers in the disk I/O pipeline, allowing those layers to provide enough data to the disk at once for optimizations involving timing writes for platter position to be done transparently to your program.

Often — almost all the time, I'd guess — if your program is simply streaming data sequentially quickly enough, even without any concurrency the disk can still be kept at a high level of efficiency, because the buffers are large enough to ensure that for any writeable block that goes under the write head, there's a block of data ready to write to it.

Naturally, SSDs change the analysis significantly. Latency on the physical media is no longer an issue, but there are lots more different ways to build an SSD, and each will come with different performance characteristics. On top of that, the technology for SSDs is still changing quickly. The people who design and build SSDs, their controllers, and even the operating systems that use them, work hard to ensure that even naïve programs work efficiently.

So, in general, just write your code naïvely. It's a lot less work to do so, and in most cases it'll work just as well. If you do decide to measure performance, and find that you can make disk I/O work more efficiently by writing to multiple files asynchronously, plan on rechecking your results periodically over time. Changes to disk technology can easily render your optimizations null and void, or even counter-productive.

Related reading:

[How to handle large numbers of concurrent disk write requests as efficiently as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421797)
[outputing dictionary optimally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9913788)
[Performance creating multiple small files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180214)
[What is the maximum number of simultaneous I/O operations in .net 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26663108)

Comment: Thank you, so much for taking the time to explain this